# How can I make 2 columns side-by-side to each other on this html table?

Tags: html, css, powershell

I'm writing a hardware report powershell script that exports the data to an HTML table. I have it working great, but as I go through to clean it up and make it look prettier, I would really like to make 2 columns for a cleaner look to the html document. Basically where "Operating System" would be on the left and "System Model" would be on the right to fill the whole page, not just stacked on top of each other like I'm viewing it on mobile. How can I go about doing this?

Here is a stripped down version of what I have:

```
$header = @"
<style>

    h1 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #e68a00;
        font-size: 28px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #000099;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    table {
        font-size: 12px;
        border: 0px; 
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    td {
        padding: 4px;
        margin: 0px;
        border: 0;
    }

    th {
        background: #395870;
        background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 11px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        padding: 10px 15px;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
        background: #f0f0f2;
    }

    #CreationDate {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        color: #ff3300;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

</style>
"@
    
    $hostname = hostname
    $ComputerName = "<h1>Computer name: $hostname</h1>"
    
    
    $OSinfo = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Property Version,Caption,BuildNumber,Manufacturer, InstallDate -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>Operating System</h2>"
    $SYSinfo = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | ConvertTo-Html -As List -Property Manufacturer, Model, SystemFamily, Description, ChassisSKUNumber, SystemSKUNumber, SystemType -Fragment -PreContent "<h2>System Model</h2>"
    
    $body = @(
    $ComputerName
    $OSinfo
    $SYSinfo
    )
    
    $Report = ConvertTo-HTML -Body "$body" -Head $header -Title "Computer Information Report" -PostContent "<p id='CreationDate'>Creation Date: $(Get-Date)</p>"
    $Report | Out-File "$drive\TEST.html"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could *shamelessly* copy the example CSS used in [**Side-by-side Tables**](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_table_side_by_side.asp) :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .row {
      margin-left: -5px;
      margin-right: -5px;
    }

    .column {
      float: left;
      width: 50%;
      padding: 5px;
    }

    .row::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }

    table {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 12px;
      border: 0px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    h1 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #e68a00;
      font-size: 28px;
    }

    h2 {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #000099;
      font-size: 16px;
    }

    td {
      padding: 4px;
      margin: 0px;
      border: 0;
    }

    th {
      background: #395870;
      background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 11px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      padding: 10px 15px;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
      background: #f0f0f2;
    }

    #CreationDate {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      color: #ff3300;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Computer name: edited</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <h2>Operating System</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Version:</td>
          <td>10.0.19044</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Caption:</td>
          <td>Microsoft Windows 10 Home Single Language</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>BuildNumber:</td>
          <td>19044</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Manufacturer:</td>
          <td>Microsoft Corporation</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>InstallDate:</td>
          <td>edited</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h2>System Model</h2>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Manufacturer:</td>
          <td>edited</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Model:</td>
          <td>edited</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SystemFamily:</td>
          <td>edited</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Description:</td>
          <td>edited</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>ChassisSKUNumber:</td>
          <td>NA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SystemSKUNumber:</td>
          <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>SystemType:</td>
          <td>x64-based PC</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <table>
    </table>
    <p id='CreationDate'>Creation Date: 05/18/2023 17:10:23</p>
</body>

</html>
```

```bash
$header = @'
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-right: -5px;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 5px;
}

.row::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  border: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #e68a00;
  font-size: 28px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000099;
  font-size: 16px;
}

td {
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0;
}

th {
  background: #395870;
  background: linear-gradient(#49708f, #293f50);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f0f0f2;
}

#CreationDate {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #ff3300;
  font-size: 12px;
}
</style>
'@

$convertToHtmlSplat = @{
    As         = 'List'
    Fragment   = $true
    PreContent = '<h2>Operating System</h2>'
    Property   = @(
        'Version'
        'Caption'
        'BuildNumber'
        'Manufacturer'
        'InstallDate'
    )
}

$OSinfo = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem | ConvertTo-Html @convertToHtmlSplat

$convertToHtmlSplat = @{
    As         = 'List'
    Fragment   = $true
    PreContent = '<h2>System Model</h2>'
    Property   = @(
        'Manufacturer'
        'Model'
        'SystemFamily'
        'Description'
        'ChassisSKUNumber'
        'SystemSKUNumber'
        'SystemType'
    )
}

$SYSinfo = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_ComputerSystem | ConvertTo-Html @convertToHtmlSplat

$convertToHtmlSplat = @{
    Head        = $header
    Title       = 'Computer Information Report'
    PostContent = "<p id='CreationDate'>Creation Date: $(Get-Date)</p>"
    Body        = @(
        "<h1>Computer name: $env:ComputerName</h1>"
        '<div class="row">'
        '<div class="column">'
        $OSinfo
        '</div>'
        '<div class="column">'
        $SYSinfo
        '</div>'
        '</div>'
    )
}

ConvertTo-Html @convertToHtmlSplat | Out-File test.html
```

Comment: You mad lad, this is exactly it. Thank you abundantly.

Comment: @AaronJK :) glad it was helpful